Using a struct property inside an Observable object
I'm just taking some time to explore SwiftUI / Observable a little more in depth and specifically looking at dependency injection via the SwiftUI Environment.
I have the following setup:
Code sample
@Observable
class AppState {
    var dataRepository = DataRepository()
}

struct DataRepository {
    private(set) var isLoading = false
    
    mutating func downloadData() async -> String {
        isLoading = true

        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3))

        isLoading = false
        return "Some data"
    }
}

Then this AppState is injected to the app and views where it's used
@main
struct DependencyInjectionApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .environment(AppState())
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(AppState.self) private var appState
    
    @State private var name: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if appState.dataRepository.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                Text(name)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .task {
            name = await appState.dataRepository.downloadData()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .environment(AppState())
}

This code causes...

The name to update to "Some data"
No progress view to show while loading inside

On inspection this is because...

The @State for the name property updates once the download happens and redraws the view
The isLoading is inside a struct inside of an Observable class so doesn't redraw the view

If I...

Change the isLoading to be on the AppState this causes a redraw (via AppState being an @Observable)
Change the DataRepository to be a class with @Observable then this also causes redrawing

But...
I'd have expected the fact DataRepository is a value type would cause the @Observable AppState to see something has changed and cause a redraw to SwiftUI, which doesn't seem to be the case
Am I missing something or is this just a limitation of @Observable?

you've got things the wrong way round. Your .task code should call the async func in your struct and set the result on your model object.

also environment(AppState()) is a memory leak, you shouldn't init objects in body like that because they are lost every time body is called.

@malhal good shout, the code was just for demo but a good point in case anyone copies and pastes

Yes, this is a limitation of @Observable. The @Observable macro works by adding special getters and setters to the class's properties, to track which properties are accessed and modified. That is, it only observes changes when the property setter is called.
Try expanding the @Observable macro and the @ObservationTracked macro that the former generates!
In your code, the setter for dataRepository is only called once for each call of downloadData, even when isLoading is set twice in the body of downloadData. This is just how mutating methods work. They call the setter of whatever property they are called on, only after they return. When downloadData returns, isLoading is set back to false, so the change to true is not observed.
Moving isLoading to AppState causes the @Observable macro to add the special getters and setters to it, so each call of isLoading's setter will be observed. The same applies when you make DataRepository an observable class.
Only as a proof of concept, you can call the setter of dataRepository by injecting the instance of AppState into DataRepository:
@Observable
class AppState {
    var dataRepository = DataRepository()
    
    init() {
        dataRepository.appState = self
    }
}

struct DataRepository {
    private(set) var isLoading = false
    var appState: AppState?
    
    mutating func downloadData() async -> String {
        // this calls the setter of dataRepository
        appState?.dataRepository.isLoading = true
        
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3))

        // this calls the setter of dataRepository
        appState?.dataRepository.isLoading = false
        
        return "Some data"
    }
}

Of course, this doesn't make much sense in practice.
